# CPU does not support virtualization. How can I use genymotion emulator for android studio then?

Tags: virtualization, genymotion

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) 32 bit. I have Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2200 @ 2.20GHz × 2 that does not support virtualization. How can I run a genymotion emulator for android studio....

Answer (score 0):

just search ubuntu genymotion - you'll get http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-android-emulator-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion is an Android virtual machine, not an emulator. Your processor must support virtualization in order to host a virtual machine, period.  Your alternative is to use an Android Virtual Device (AVD), also known as an emulator. You can download AVDs for various API levels via Android Studio under *Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager*, and then configure them under *Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager*.